# How do I pass a PHP array to Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json, vue.js

I have trainers.inc.php file which generates array with data retreived from a database :

```
$trainers_meta[0] = array('Id' => $id, 'Name' => $name, 'Description' => $description, 'Experience' => $experience, 'Focus' => $focus, 'Fileformat' => $format, 'File' => $file);
```

I encoded the PHP array as JSON using the PHP `json_encode()` function :

```
$trainers_meta = json_encode($trainers_meta);
```

The conversion went without any warnings or errors for which I specifically checked. At the top of my `index.php` file I require the `trainers.inc.php` file :

```
require_once('trainers.inc.php');
```

At the bottom of the file I create a JavaScript variable with the converted JSON contents inside of a `<script>` tag :

```
<script>
    let trainersMeta = <?php echo $trainers_meta;?>;
</script>
```

At the bottom of the file I link to the Vue.js CDN :

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@3.2.26"></script>
```

Above in the `index.php` file I try to echo out HTML code using the `v-for` attribute of Vue.js :

```
<div class="container" v-for="trainer in trainersMeta">
   <h1>Should appear on the page</h1>
</div>
```

But no content ever appears. My IDE tells me a warning that the trainersMeta variable is undefined. I get that Vue.js must see the variable before it's loaded which is why I initialize it before actually importing it's CDN. Besides it doesn't matter what file or position do I put the `<script>` tag at the variable is always undefined. I cannot simply initialize the variable inside of the Vue.js code because Vue.js is completely incompatible with PHP in this regard. Even putting all the Vue.js code inside of a `<script>` tag in `index.php` doesn't work and Vue.js code simply never compiles at all because of it. How can I pass a PHP JSON encoded variable to Vue.js for it to see/use it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For what it is worth, I've never used Vue.js before today. Everything I've gleaned, I picked up in about 5 minutes from the [documentation](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/introduction.html).

You've:

- created a variable (`trainersMeta`)
- built a template (`<div class="container"`)
- loaded the Vue library (`<script`).

You **haven't**:

- written a Vue application to use that data

You need to create an object that has a data method which returns the object you've created, and you need to call `Vue.createApp` with that object and then mount it on a container around your template.

Such:

```html
<script>
  let trainersMeta = {
    Id: 123,
    Name: 'Bob'
  };
</script>
<div id="app">
  <div class="container" v-for="trainer in trainersMeta">
    <h1>Should appear on the page</h1>
    {{trainer}}
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@3.2.26"></script>

<script>
  const Trainers = {
    data() {
      return {
        trainersMeta
      }
    }
  }

  Vue.createApp(Trainers).mount('#app')
</script>
```

Comment: Huge thank you for the example that you supplied. You're right I wasn't mounting the variable with the app. Trust me though that I've spend hours upon hours scrolling through the documentation and various websites before I asked the question in the first place and could not find a single relatable example which would point me to the solution. It's pretty simple yet it was so hard atleast for me. Thank you.